# How does += makes my code word?

Tags: python

**On Codecademy**

```
    prices = {
    "banana" : 4,
    "apple"  : 2,
    "orange" : 1.5,
    "pear"   : 3,
}

stock = {
    "banana" : 6,
    "apple"  : 0,
    "orange" : 32,
    "pear"   : 15,
}

total = 0
for key in prices:
    print prices[key] * stock[key]
    total += prices[key] * stock[key]

print total
```

If I changed the code to,

```
total = prices[key] * stock[key]
```

it doesn't work. The correct total doesn't print out. How does **+=** change my code?

Comment: FYI `a += b`  is equivalent to `a = a + b`

Comment: @Jakub "equivalent", but not really. In python the two are subtly different when it comes to mutable objects.

Comment: `total += prices[key] * stock[key]` is syntactically equivalent to `total = total + prices[key] * stock[key]`

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:

Because you want a running total not only the last product.

---

Long answer:

The `=` operator just assigns a **new** value to the variable on the left side, the `+=` operator **updates** the value on the left side by adding the right side to it.

You could also do:

```
total = 0
for key in prices:
    total = total + prices[key] * stock[key]
```

or even without the `for`-loop:

```
total = sum(prices[key] * stock[key] for key in prices)
```

Answer (score -1):

Using `+=` is saying "Take the left side of the `=, and add it to the right side of the`=`, and assign it the same variable name".

To expand your code:

`total += prices[key] * stock[key]`

is equivalent with immutable objects to:

`total = total + prices[key] * stock[key]`

EDIT: For the people on high-horses screaming about interactions with mutable objects in a question whose problem is not about mutable object interaction:

The code listed above the edit is not equivalent in the case of mutable objects (such as `list` or `dict`), because the `+=` operator keeps the same reference of the variable on the left side. Meanwhile, using `+` separately from `=` will result in a new list reference.

For example:

```
li = []
print(id(li)) 
li += [1]
print(id(li)) # they are the same id
```

vs.

```
li = []
print(id(li)) 
li = li + [1]
print(id(li)) # they are different ids
```

Comment: "Equivalent", but not really. In python the two are subtly different when it comes to mutable objects.

Comment: @AndrasDeak Except this is not a case of operations on mutable objects.

Comment: @AndrasDeak please elaborate for the class, i wasn't aware they aren't exactly equivalent

Comment: NoticeMeSenpai I agree, now OP has ints and they *are* equivalent, but one should make it clear that this is type-dependent. @Nullman: try `t = []; print(id(t)); t += ['foo']; print(id(t)); t = t + ['bar']; print(id(t))`. The former mutates the existing list; the latter rebinds the name `t` to a new list.

Comment: @AndrasDeak You're talking about referencing with mutable objects, albeit a true point, is a non-relevant point for this problem.

Comment: I mostly wanted to have it noted that += can behave subtly; as OP is clearly learning the basics of the language and this might bite them in the butt in the future. But yeah, your answer is even better this way (despite the passive agressive tone).